# Creating a downloadable link from a string that must be compressed due to string length

Tags: javascript, html, zlib, download

I have a string (~2MB) which represents a CSV that I need to make downloadable on a page. This is what I was doing to make the string downloadable and it worked fine for smaller files.

```
const csvContentEncoded = encodeURIComponent("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + csvContent);

const element = document.createElement("a");
element.setAttribute("href", csvContentEncoded);
element.setAttribute("download", "filename.csv");
element.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

But for files around (~2MB) this no longer works on Chrome and results in downloaded files titled "download: Failed - Network error" which cannot be retried. Oddly, these download perfectly fine on firefox and chrome. After some investigation it seems to be specifically related to the file size and not due to other things (such as network request timing). That said, I haven't been able to find anything conclusive around chrome and max size for elements with the "download" HTML attribute.

I'm now attempting to zip the content before setting on the element. Here's my code:

```
const zip = zlib.deflateSync("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + csvContent).toString("base64");
const csvContent = encodeURIComponent(zip);
const element = document.createElement("a");
element.setAttribute("href", csvContent);
element.setAttribute("download", "filename.csv"); // should I be changing this to a .zip or something?

element.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

But this doesn't work. Chrome displays the download file as "Failed - Server problem". It also doesn't work on firefox of safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a blob. Using blobs you can download files from few MBs to GB depending on which browser you are using.

```
const csvData = new Blob([csvContent], { type: 'text/csv' }); 
const csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
const element = document.createElement("a");
element.setAttribute("href",csvUrl);
element.setAttribute("download", "filename.csv");
element.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

There are libraries also which will help you achieve this like StreamSaver, FileSaver etc.